Calling contentWindow.postMessage on iframe has no effect
In the vue component below sending a message to an iframe using the iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(...) call has no effect.
The component waits for a message from the iframe and sends a response message to the iframe in the mesageHandler(...). Within the messageHandler(...) there are two ways to send the message to the iframe:

Calling sendResponse1(...) works as expected
Calling sendResponse2() has no effect.

The component has also to send the message in the onBeforeUnmount(...) lifecycle hook. There calling sendResponse1(...) is not an option because there is no event present that has to be passed as argument.
The origin of the iframe is not the same as the origin of the embedding component. The content at the origin is not under our control.
The problem is not browser specific. It persists in Edge and Chrome.
Vue Component
<template>
  <div ref="elm" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  src: string;
}>();

const elm = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
const box = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);
const iframe = ref<HTMLIFrameElement | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  if (!elm.value) {
    return;
  }

  box.value = document.createElement('div');

  iframe.value = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.value.src = props.src;

  box.value.appendChild(iframe.value);
  elm.value.appendChild(box.value);

  window.addEventListener('message', messageHandler, { passive: true });
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  iframe?.value?.remove?.();
  box?.value?.remove?.();
  window.removeEventListener('message', messageHandler);
  // sendResponse1(...) <-- cannot call from here because there is no event
  sendResponse2();  // NOK does not work
});

function messageHandler(event: MessageEvent) {
  if (!iframe.value || event.origin !== new URL(iframe.value.src).origin) {
    return;
  }

  // Call 1 OK: message sent
  sendResponse1(event);

  // Call 2 NOK: message not sent
  sendResponse2();
}

function sendResponse1(event: MessageEvent) {
  event.source?.postMessage({ message: 'Response' }, <any>event.origin);
}

function sendResponse2() {
  iframe.value?.contentWindow?.postMessage(
    'Response',
    new URL(iframe.value.src).origin,
  );
}
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Some stylesheets */
</style>


just a minor point, you say The problem is not browser specific. and then It persists in Edge and Chrome. - so, you've literally tested it on a single browser engine - chromium - which will behave the same on those two browsers. But, you are right, this will behave the same in all other, chromium based and non-chromium based, browsers

iframe.value?.contentWindow?.postMessage() - you're using optional chaining there, so have you verified the full chain actually exists?

@C3roe, yes, the full chain exists.

And new URL(iframe.value.src).origin is also giving the correct, expected origin? Does anything change, if you provide * instead?
